# How can I cache view data within MVC correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

```
  [OutputCache(Duration=100)]
        public ViewDataDictionary IndexCache()
        {
            ViewDataDictionary dic = new ViewDataDictionary();

      // here I add the data to dic and MVC cached it.

            return dic;
        }
 public ActionResult Index(string param1)
        {
            var x = IndexCache();

            foreach(var y in x)
            {
                ViewData.Add(y);
            }

            return PartialView("/home/index.cshtml");
        }
```

Is this implementation the right way to cache the viewdata?

If not, please guide me how I can got it.

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking. Providing at least name of the function you are trying to call and where you are trying to call it would be helpful.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I like the MichaC's answer but I can't implement OutoutCache. Actually My layout file have right side which contain user based data that is come from Controller base class. What I do here is just cache the data so this will never product all people same action because action work different for every logged-in user.

Comment: Maybe answer is to use `Session` (assuming you trying to "cache" per-user data)...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov My team doesn't allow me to use session. Is their something else that can help me. thanks :)

Comment: No, there is no other server side storage for per-user data directly in the Framework (depending on what is the reason not to use session state you may be able to find third party solution with similar per-user storage).

Answer (score 0):

Read [this Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs)

Put the `OutputCache` attribute above the method which returns the view data, e.g. `Index`, this should cache, whatever `Index` would return, dependent on the settings of the Attribute.

If you just want to cache data which is used across multiple views or controllers, use in process/inmemory caching with `System.Web.Caching`!

Comment: I do this.HttpContext.Cache and add the data into this. this will never gave me back my data.

Comment: It pretty much depends on what you want to cache and when. If you want to cache something for all users, use System.Web.Caching or `HttpContext.Cache`, this will globally cache something in memory, of cause you have to use it correctly... 
If you want to cache data per user you could use the Session key/value store as Alex mentioned...